# Does $f$ have directional derivatives at the origin?

Tags: derivatives, vectors, partial-derivative

Define $f:\mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ by
$$
f(x,y)=
\begin{cases}
 \frac{xy}{x^2+y^2} &\text{if}\, (x,y)\neq(0,0)\\
      0 &\text{if}\, (x,y)=(0,0)
\end{cases}
$$

How do begin this question? I know the definition of directional derivative is
$$
D_u f=\lim_{h\rightarrow 0}\frac{f((x,y)+h(u_1, u_2))-f(x,y)}{h}
$$

Can I use $\nabla f(x) \cdot u$ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use $\nabla f\cdot u$ if $f$ is differentiable at $(0, 0)$. But its partial derivatives are not continuous, so you should directly substitute $f$ to get the directional derivative.